# Regular expression to match img tag's url

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This regular expression:

```
<IMG\s([^"'>]+|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")+>
```

seems to process endlessly when given this text

```
<img src=http://www.blahblahblah.com/houses/Images/
    single_and_multi/roof/feb09/01_img_trrnjks_vol2009.jpg' />
```

I would expect it to - not find a match (quickly) - because there is only one single quote in the text. I have had this happen in C# and also using the Expresso regex tool. If the text is a lot shorter it seems to work.

Comment: +1 RoBurg. Of course the *real* thing that's wrong about the regular expression is that it's being used to parse HTML. Regex cannot adequately parse HTML. Use an HTML parser (see eg. HTML Agility Pack).

Comment: In case this helps, I've found the following Firefox Addon to be very helpful when developing regular expressions:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2077

Comment: While agreeing with the notion that parsing HTML with Regex is a bad thing, if you take this problem abstractly it does show a problem with Regex in general. I found this quite an informative exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other commenters have mentioned the complexity being the likely cause for the perfo problem.  I'd add that if you're trying to match something resembling an IMG tag, I think you want a regex more like this:

```
<IMG(\s+[a-z]+=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^\s'">]+))+>
```

Of course, there are still valid HTML variations that this regex won't catch.  Like a closing `/` (required in xhtml), or whitespace before the closing bracket.  And it will pass some invalid cases, like unsupported attribute names.

Comment: This does not catch the unquoted value which I need to do in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work. I needed to allow for more white space and the /> but it catches the IMG tags that are well formed and fails on those that are not.

It is the = before trying to catch the unquoted values that stops Regex going nuts with branching/backtracking.

Answer (score 6):

```
<IMG\s([^"'>]+|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")+>
```

Taking out a couple of branches, the start and the end:

```
([^"'>]+)+
```

How many ways can this match "hello"?

```
(hell)(o)
(hel)(lo)
(hel)(l)(o)
(he)(llo)
(he)(l)(lo)
(he)(l)(l)(o)
... and so on
```

Comment: I had thoughts along this line as well but could not think of how to avoid them and still have the same logic.

Comment: Ouch. I didn't notice the first `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one of the situations where the regex engine is backtracking a lot. Mastering Regular Expressions by Friedl has some good material on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were trying for, I think the cause of your long running is as mentioned elsewhere, due to extreme repetition caused by the greedy grab for non-quote or > being or-ed with the string processors (also using greedy ["'>] matching.

This seems to run swiftly with either correctly formatted or incorrectly formatted tags.

```
<img(\s+((\w+)=(('[^']*?')|("[^"]*?"))))+? />
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post what you are exactly trying to find or extract? Do you want to figure out what the img tag points to? That would greatly increase the chances of being able to provide a better answer.

Comment: I just want to extract all IMG tags. I am not actually changing them or parsing the contents of the IMG tag its self.